# Can't pass values to a webservice using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I don't know if my data syntax is wrong or not, but this same script when no parameter is passed is working, but when parameter is passed, it is not working. Why?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function GetAge() {
           var StrYear = document.getElementById("StringYear").value;
           var StrMonth = document.getElementById("StringMonth").value;
           var StrDay = document.getElementById("StringDay").value;
           jQuery.support.cors = true;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
               async: false,
               url: 'http://localhost:50113/Service1.asmx/GetAge',
               data: "{ StrYear: "+StrYear+", StrMonth:"+ StrMonth+"  , StrDay: "+StrDay+"  }",
               success: function (msg) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.d);
               },
               error: function (e) {
                   $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html("Unavailable");
               }
           });
         }
        </script>
```

Comment: *it is not working* means what? Any errors in the console? Is the request  correct? What about the response? (fiddler/net-tab)

Answer (score 5):

Probably you should pass data as an object, so probably you don't need

```
data: "{ StrYear: "+StrYear+", StrMonth:"+ StrMonth+"  , StrDay: "+StrDay+"  }",
```

But

```
data: { StrYear: StrYear, StrMonth: StrMonth, StrDay: StrDay },
```

Comment: thanx for the code but its having no effect is it the problem of my jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Pass your data in this format

```
   data: '{ "StrYear": "' + StrYear+ '","StrMonth":"' + StrMonth+ '" ,"StrDay": "' + StrDay+ '" }',
```

Comment: thanx for the code but its having no effect is it the problem of my jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: use this to check what is the problem                               error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {                                             alert(xhr.responseText);alert(thrownError);},

Answer (score 1):

try `dataType: "jsonp",` instead of `dataType: "json",`

and

```
data: { StrYear: StrYear, StrMonth: StrMonth, StrDay: StrDay },
```